# DAO.Recordset returns only one record when executing in codese

Tags: vba, ms-access-2007, dao

This statement always returns only one record everytime when its executed

```
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("Select book_name from book")
Dim i As Integer
For i = 0 To rs.RecordCount - 1
lbBooks.AddItem rs!book_name
rs.MoveNext
Next
```

what could ebe the cause

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe that the `RecordCount` property of a `Recordset` is set dynamically to the amount of data that has been read from the cursor. That is, when it's first opened, it's set to 1; if you do `rs.MoveLast`, it will set it to the actual number of records in the set. However, you then have the problem of moving back to the start: you must have the recordset opened in a particular mode (which I forgot, from the top of my head) to be able to arbitrarily move the cursor pointer back and forward.

The usual way of iterating through a cursor is to use a `while` loop, checking for the cursor's end of file:

```
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("Select book_name from book")
Dim i As Integer

i = 0 
While Not rs.EOF
  lbBooks.AddItem rs!book_name
  rs.MoveNext
  i = i + 1
Wend
```

Comment: thanks for responding, but even when i step through the code, the record-set property is clearly seen as `record-count = 1`